# Avoid having multiple delete files

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I have a webpage with a pretty big CMS behind it, where you can add news, add pictures and other things. And of course, you can delete them as well.

You simply click delete, and it leads you to the delete script which deletes the row from the table. Problem is that I have like 4-5 deletescripts that look exactly the same, except that they delete from different tables. I would like the table to be a variable, which tracks what subpage the user came from, so I would only need one delete script, instead of multiple.

This is the button that you click to delete something:

```
<a href='deletenews.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>'>DELETE</a>
```

Notice that it goes to delte"news".php, it would be nice if it was just delete.php.

The delete script is as follows:

```
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']) {

    } else {
        include 'index.php';
        die ("<script> alert(You have to be logged in.');</script>");
    }

mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query("DELETE FROM news WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'") or die(mysql_error());

header('Location: forside.php');
```

I would like there to be a variable, instead of "news". Like $delete. But that variable would need to know from what table it is supposed to delete stuff from. Is there any way to go about doing this? I'm willing to change all my code for it, because I think that is better practice.

Comment: Soooo...if you wrote code that works for the `id`, why can't you replicate the same mechanism for the table name? You know you can send more than one GET variable, right? And you know a mysql query in PHP is a string, right?

Comment: I'm going to erase your database... see about injection

Comment: Strawberry: Well, it probably ain't secure, but you have to be logged in to input anything at all, so it ain't really a problem. The login script is pretty secure. I'm in the middle of learning PHP/SQL.
Sergiu: How would you do that?

Comment: Again, what's the difficulty in using `$_GET['table']` and then `mysql_query("DELETE FROM " . $_GET['table'] . " WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'")`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this check:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
if ($id)
    if ($table == 'news') {
        // do something
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
        // or this:
        //mysql_query("DELETE FROM news WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
    } elseif ($table == 'posts') {
        // do something
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
        // or this:
        //mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        die("You can not delete records from $table table");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue here. I want the table name "news" to be a variable. Like "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id". But I need to know how to identify what table it is. Because there are more than news you can delete on this page.